# Contents of csv file getting displayed on webpage instead of a proper file download

Tags: java, file, csv, download

Problem: Contents of a CSV file are getting displayed as page contents if the number of records is large.

Expected: File download.

The request gets fired from another page via window.open(url); Following is the url handler.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void handler(HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap map, @RequestParam("itemPk") long pk, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()));
    try {
        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            String[] row = new String[] {"asdr", "10", "sourajit", "34.567", "06-DEC-2015", "awx445"};
            data.add(row);
        }
        csvWriter.writeAll(data);

        response.setContentType("text/csv"); 
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=volcs.csv");


    }  finally {
        csvWriter.flush();
        csvWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Same behavior for GET or POST. 
(For POST, opening a new window with a html form)

Answer (score 0):

This is because a Writer instance is used for generating the response.

We need to treat it as bytes.

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 
out.write(baos.toByteArray());
baos.writeTo(out);
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add headers to tell browser that its attachment in the response. Check the below!

```java
String filename = "volcs.csv";
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
response.setContentLength((int)f.length());
//response.setContentLength(-1);
//response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + filename);
```